# looking for an efficient data structure to do a quick searches

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I have a list of elements around 1000. Each element (objects that i read from the file, hence i can arrange them efficiently at the beginning) containing  contains 4 variables. So now I am doing the following, which is very inefficient at grand scheme of things:

```
void func(double value1, double value2, double value3)
{

       fooArr[1000];

       for(int i=0;i<1000; ++i) 
       {
                   //they are all numeric! ranges are < 1000
                  if(fooArr[i].a== value1
                       && fooArr[i].b >= value2;
                       && fooArr[i].c <= value2; //yes again value2  
                       && fooArr[i].d <= value3; 
                   )
                   {
                            /* yay found now do something!*/
                    }
       } 
}
```

Space is not too important!

**MODIFIED per REQUEST**

Comment: Has this actually caused a performance issue or are you just assuming that it will?  In what context is it used?  Is this lookup run trillions of times, or is it run occassionally?

Comment: please reformat the code block.

Comment: Uhm. Optimizing a loop with three thousand integer comparisons looks like a premature optimization. Is this really the slow part of your application?

Comment: YES that "if" causes a huge performance issue, as the function is called on order of 100k times. So I want to avoid that altogether and and invest sometime during readin in those objects

Comment: @Simon Svensson: oprofile told it spends the most time in that "if"

Comment: @Andrei Chikatilo, it's not fun when all the SO users parrot some quote about premature optimizations is it? :) Yes, some peopel in the *real world* actually do care about performance (also those people who know what "Power Wall" refers to might be interested as well)

Comment: How constant are your constants? i.e. could you pre-filter the list of objects based on those constants?

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something in my description (Eh, I am Russian), but this is a real problem, from a real-time system that needs performance tuned!

Comment: sorry they are parameters passed to the function but dont change in the loop

Comment: Reorder the comparisons from the least likely to occur (probably the `==` one) to the most likely. If `SomeOtherConstant` and `Some VeryOtherConstant` are "large" switch the comparisons of members `b` and `c`.

Comment: @Bobby Shaftoe:  Thing is, we've had innumerable micro-optimization questions going through where the answer doesn't matter in the least.  At this point, I'd suggest that anybody asking such a question include something like "The profiler shows this as the hot spot." or something to establish that yes, this question is worth addressing.

Comment: @Andrei: What is the range of values for `a`? Depending on this you could do a constant time lookup.

Comment: a is quite small actually, 10 values -- packed into enum... please expain!

Comment: I've added a response with a O(1) lookup for the objects on which to apply the Predicate below (in the mass). Pigeon-hole do wonders for speed, and it's not necessary to restrict it to the '==' case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If space isn't too important the easiest thing to do is to create a hash based on "a"  Depending on how many conflicts you get on "a" it may make sense to make each node in the hash table point to a binary tree based off of "b"  If b has a lot of conflicts, do the same for c.

That first index into the hash, depending on how many conflicts, will save you a lot of time for very little coding or data structures work.

Comment: For so few possible values it doesn't make sense to use a hash, the value can be used as an index directly.

Comment: @Mark: Using the value as the index is just a special case of a hash; a very simple hash function f(i) = i

Answer (score 3):

First, sort the list on increasing a and decreasing b.  Then build an index on a (values are integers from 0 to 999.  So, we've got

```
int a_index[1001];  // contains starting subscript for each value
a_index[1000] = 1000;

for (i = a_index[value1]; i < a_index[value1 + 1] && fooArr[i].b >= value2; ++i)
{
   if (fooArr[i].c <= value2 && fooArr[i].d <= value3) /* do stuff */
}
```

Assuming I haven't made a mistake here, this limits the search to the subscripts where a and b are valid, which is likely to cut your search times drastically.

Comment: You're using `value1` as an array index, but it's a `double`. Smells suspicious, but I can see why you did it after the "`a` is an `enum`" comment.

Comment: I missed that.  However, there's two possibilities.  Either they really should be integers, or he shouldn't be comparing them for equality.  If they are doubles, then value1 needs to be coerced to int and the a_index table will be slightly different.  No real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are have only three properties to match you could use a hash table. When performing a search, you use the hash table (which indexes the a-property) to find all entries where a matches `SomeConstant`. After that you check if b and c also match your constants. This way you can reduce the number of comparisons. I think this would speed the search up quite a bit.

Other than that you could build three binary search trees. One sorted by each property. After searching all three of them you perform your action for those which match your values in each tree.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've said (in both the question and the comments) there are only a *very* few values for `a` (something like 10).

That being the case, I'd build an index on the values of `a` where each one points directly to all the elements in the `fooArr` with that value of `a`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<foo *> > index(num_a_values);

for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    index[fooArr[i].a].push_back(&fooArr[i]);
```

Then when you get a value to look up an item, you go directly to those for which `fooArr[i].a==value1`:

```
std::vector<foo *> const &values = index[value1];
for (int i=0; i<values.size(); i++) {
    if (value2 <= values[i]->b
        && value2 >= values[i]->c
        && value3 >= values[i]->d) {
            // yay, found something
        }
}
```

This way, instead of looking at 1000 items in fooArray each time, you look at an average of 100 each time. If you want still more speed, the next step would be to sort the items in each vector in the index based on the value of `b`. This will let you find the lower bound for value2 using a binary search instead of a linear search, reducing ~50 comparisons to ~10. Since you've sorted it by `b`, from that point onward you don't have to compare `value2` to `b` -- you know exactly where the rest of the numbers that satisfy the inequality are, so you only have to compare to `c` and `d`.

You might also consider another approach based on the limited range of the numbers: 0 to 1000 can be represented in 10 bits. Using some bit-twiddling, you could combine three fields into a single 32-bit number, which would let the compiler compare all three at once, instead of in three separate operations. Getting this right is a little tricky, but once you to, it could roughly triple the speed again.

Answer (score 1):

I think using kd-tree would be appropriate.
If there aren't many conflicts with `a` then hashing/indexing `a` might resolve your problem.

Anyway if that doesn't work I suggest using kd-tree.

First do a table of multiple kd-trees. Index them with `a`.

Then implement a kd-tree for each `a` value with 3-dimensions in directions `b`, `c`, `d`.

Then when searching - first index to appropriate kd-tree with `a`, and then search from kd-tree with your limits. Basically you'll do a range search.

[Kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree)

You'll get your answer in `O(L^(2/3)+m)`, where `L` is the number of elements in appropriate kd-tree and `m` is the number of matching points.

Something better that I found is [Range Tree](http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/RangeSearchTree.aspx). This might be what you are looking for.
It's fast. It'll answer your query in `O(log^3(L)+m)`. (Unfortunately don't know about Range Tree much.)

Comment: also balance kd-tree as much as possible before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's have a go.

First of all, the == operator calls for a pigeon-hole approach. Since we are talking about int values in the [0,1000] range, a simple table is good.

```
std::vector<Bucket1> myTable(1001, /*MAGIC_1*/); // suspense
```

The idea of course is that you will find `YourObject` instance in the bucket defined for its `a` attribute value... nothing magic so far.

Now on the new stuff.

```
 && fooArr[i].b >= value2
 && fooArr[i].c <= value2 //yes again value2
 && fooArr[i].d <= value3
```

The use of `value2` is tricky, but you said you did not care for space right ;) ?

```
 typedef std::vector<Bucket2> Bucket1;
 /*MAGIC_1*/ <-- Bucket1(1001, /*MAGIC_2*/) // suspense ?
```

A `BucketA` instance will have in its ith position all instances of `YourObject` for which `yourObject.c <= i <= yourObject.b`

And now, same approach with the `d`.

```
 typedef std::vector< std::vector<YourObject*> > Bucket2;
 /*MAGIC_2*/ <-- Bucket2(1001)
```

The idea is that the `std::vector<YourObject*>` at index ith contains a pointer to all instances of `YourObject` for which `yourObject.d <= i`

Putting it altogether!

```
class Collection:
{
public:
  Collection(size_t aMaxValue, size_t bMaxValue, size_t dMaxValue);
    // prefer to use unsigned type for unsigned values

  void Add(const YourObject& i);

  // Pred is a unary operator taking a YourObject& and returning void
  template <class Pred>
  void Apply(int value1, int value2, int value3, Pred pred);

  // Pred is a unary operator taking a const YourObject& and returning void
  template <class Pred>
  void Apply(int value1, int value2, int value3, Pred pred) const;

private:
  // List behaves nicely with removal,
  // if you don't plan to remove, use a vector
  // and store the position within the vector
  // (NOT an iterator because of reallocations)
  typedef std::list<YourObject> value_list;

  typedef std::vector<value_list::iterator> iterator_vector;
  typedef std::vector<iterator_vector> bc_buckets;
  typedef std::vector<bc_buckets> a_buckets;
  typedef std::vector<a_buckets> buckets_t;

  value_list m_values;
  buckets_t m_buckets;
}; // class Collection

Collection::Collection(size_t aMaxValue, size_t bMaxValue, size_t dMaxValue) :
  m_values(),
  m_buckets(aMaxValue+1,
            a_buckets(bMaxValue+1, bc_buckets(dMaxValue+1))
           )
  )
{
}

void Collection::Add(const YourObject& object)
{
  value_list::iterator iter = m_values.insert(m_values.end(), object);

  a_buckets& a_bucket = m_buckets[object.a];
  for (int i = object.c; i <= object.b; ++i)
  {
    bc_buckets& bc_bucket = a_bucket[i];
    for (int j = 0; j <= object.d; ++j)
    {
      bc_bucket[j].push_back(index);
    }
  }
} // Collection::Add

template <class Pred>
void Collection::Apply(int value1, int value2, int value3, Pred pred)
{
  index_vector const& indexes = m_buckets[value1][value2][value3];
  BOOST_FOREACH(value_list::iterator it, indexes)
  {
    pred(*it);
  }
} // Collection::Apply<Pred>

template <class Pred>
void Collection::Apply(int value1, int value2, int value3, Pred pred) const
{
  index_vector const& indexes = m_buckets[value1][value2][value3];

  // Promotion from value_list::iterator to value_list::const_iterator is ok
  // The reverse is not, which is why we keep iterators
  BOOST_FOREACH(value_list::const_iterator it, indexes)
  {
    pred(*it);
  }
} // Collection::Apply<Pred>
```

So, admitedly adding and removing items to that collections will cost.

Furthermore, you have `(aMaxValue + 1) * (bMaxValue + 1) * (dMaxValue + 1) std::vector<value_list::iterator>` stored, which is a lot.

However, `Collection::Apply` complexity is roughly `k` applications of `Pred` where `k` is the number of items which match the parameters.

*I am looking for a review there, not sure I got all the indexes right oO*

Comment: I think it could be explained simpler `list<YourObject*>[][][] = new list<YourObject*>[aMaxValue + 1][ bMaxValue + 1 ][dMaxValue+1]`... and then precalculate everything. Or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

Look, this is just a linear search.  It would be nice if you could do a search that scales up better, but your complex matching requirements make it unclear to me whether it's even possible to, say, keep it sorted and use a binary search.

Having said this, perhaps one possibility is to generate some indexes.  The main index might be a dictionary keyed on the `a` property, associating it with a list of elements with the same value for that property.  Assuming the values for this property are well-distributed, it would immediately eliminate the overwhelming majority of comparisons.

If the property has a limited number of values, then you could consider adding an additional index which sorts items by `b` and maybe even another that sorts by `c` (but in the opposite order).

Answer (score 0):

If your app is already using a database then just put them in a table and use a query to find it. I use mysql in a few of my apps and would recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

First for each `a` do different table...

do a tabel `num` for numbers that have the same `a`.

do 2 index tabels each with 1000 rows.

index table contains integer representation of a split which numbers
will be involved.

For example let's say you have values in the array
(ignoring `a` because we have a table for each `a` value)

```
b = 96  46  47  27  40  82   9  67   1  15
c = 76  23  91  18  24  20  15  43  17  10
d = 44  30  61  33  21  52  36  70  98  16
```

then the index table values for the row 50, 20 are:

```
idx[a].bc[50] = 0000010100
idx[a].d[50]  = 1101101001
idx[a].bc[20] = 0001010000
idx[a].d[20]  = 0000000001
```

so let's say you do func(a, 20, 50).
Then to get which numbers are involved you do:

```
g = idx[a].bc[20] & idx[a].d[50];
```

Then `g` has 1-s for each number you have to deal with. If you don't
need the array values then you can just do a `populationCount` on `g`. And
do the inner thing `popCount(g)` times.

You can do

```
tg = g
n = 0
while (tg > 0){
  if(tg & 1){
    // do your stuff
  }
  tg = tg >>> 1;
  n++;
}
```

maybe it can be improved in `tg = tg >>> 1; n++;` part by skipping over many zeros, but I have no idea if that's possible. It should considerably faster than your current approach because all variables for the loop are in registers.

Answer (score 0):

As pmg said, the idea is to eliminate as many comparisons as possible. Obviously you won't have 4000 comparisons. That would require that all 1000 elements pass the first test, which would then be redundant. Apparently there are only 10 values of `a`, hence 10% passes that check. So, you'd do 1000 + 100 + ? + ? checks. Let's assume +50+25, for a total of 1175.

You'd need to know how a,b,c,d and value1, 2 and 3 are distributed to decide exactly what's fastest. We only know that a can have 10 values, and we presume that `value1` has the same domain. In that case, binning by `a` can reduce it to an O(1) operation to get the right bin, plus the same 175 checks further on. But if b,c and value2 effectively form 50 buckets, you could find the right bucket again in O(1). Yet each bucket would now have an average of 20 elements, so you'd only need 35 tests (80% reduction). So, data distribution matters here. Once you understand your data, the algorithm will be clear.

Answer (score -1):

You can use hash_set  from Standard Template Library(STL),  this will give you very efficient implementation. complexity of your search would be O(1)

here is link: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/hash_set.html

--EDIT--

declare new Struct which will hold your variables, overload comparison operators and make  the  hash_set of this new struct.  every time you want to search,  create new object with your variables and pass it to hash_set method "find".

It seems that hash_set is not mandatory for STL, therefore you can use set and it will give you O(LogN) complexity for searching.
here is example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct Obj{

public:
       Obj(double a, double b, double c, double d){
                this->a = a;
                this->b = b;
                this->c = c;
                this->d = d;
       }

       double a;
       double b;
       double c;
       double d;
       friend bool operator < ( const Obj &l, const Obj &r )  {
              if(l.a != r.a)  return l.a < r.a;
              if(l.b != r.b) return l.a < r.b;
              if(l.c != r.c) return l.c < r.c;
              if(l.d != r.d) return l.d < r.d;
              return false;

       }
  };


 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
set<Obj> A;

A.insert( Obj(1,2,3,4));
A.insert( Obj(16,23,36,47));
A.insert(Obj(15,25,35,43));

Obj c(1,2,3,4);

A.find(c);
cout <<    A.count(c);



system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: one edit with code instead of text will score you yet another upvote == i promise

Comment: afaik this would work if the op needed an exact match, but he doesnt